# Accessing `this` in class function is undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a throttle method inside a class that takes as the second argument some class properties but I can't access the class properties because `this` is undefined.

I have reproduced the code in a simpler manner to demonstrate the issue:

```
function someThrottleFunction(a, b) {
  // doesn't really matter what is in here
}

class cname {
  constructor(prop1) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }
  func = someThrottleFunction(() => {}, this.prop1.time);
}

let a = new cname({ time: 3000 });
```

you can see a live code error demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/x7yqy933qq

Any suggestions on how to rewrite this in a working manner are greately appreciated.

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't know if this is scientifically backed, but anecdotally it's easier on the eyes for some (most?) people.

Comment: @paulsm4 Maybe it's also because of the AMOLED screens which doesn't drain power when displaying black content

Comment: Thank you, Alex - that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `func` is assigned to *before* the constructor runs:

```js
function someThrottleFunction(a, b) {
  // doesn't really matter what is in here
}

class cname {
  constructor(prop1) {
    console.log('constructor running');
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }
  func = (console.log('func being assigned to'), someThrottleFunction(() => {}, this.prop1.time));
}

let a = new cname({ time: 3000 });
```

You might assign at the end of the constructor instead:

```js
function someThrottleFunction(a, b) {
  // doesn't really matter what is in here
}

class cname {
  constructor(prop1) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.func = someThrottleFunction(() => {}, this.prop1.time);
  }
}

let a = new cname({ time: 3000 });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you intended for `func` to be a function:

```js
function someThrottleFunction(a, b) {
  console.log(b)
}

class cname {
  constructor(prop1) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }
  func() { 
    someThrottleFunction(() => {}, this.prop1.time);
  }
}

let a = new cname({ time: 3000 });
a.func()
```

**or**

```js
function someThrottleFunction(a, b) {
  console.log(b)
}

class cname {
  constructor(prop1) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }
  func = () => { 
    someThrottleFunction(() => {}, this.prop1.time);
  }
}

let a = new cname({ time: 3000 });
a.func()
```